# GCC plugin: 'internal compiler error' in passes.c

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, gcc-plugins

I have been writing a GCC inter procedural plugin where I have to insert GIMPLE statements
at certain points in the program. After this I perform a data flow analysis on the complete
program. When I am done with my analysis I am removing those newly inserted GIMPLE statements.

My analysis is getting completed but just before exiting from it the following message is generated:

> internal compiler error: in execute_ipa_pass_list, at passes.c:1817

This is surely because of the insertion of GIMPLE statements, if I don't do that I won't get this error message.

Could anyone help me out and explain what is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when GCC code contains an assertion which turns out to be `false`.

The line 1817 in `passes.c` (which is part of the GCC sources, in the `gcc` sub-directory of the GCC source tree) has a piece of code which looks like:

`gcc_assert (some_condition);`

In your case, `some_condition` was false, but the compiler expects it to be always `true` (this is why the author of the code wrote the assertion in the first place).

You did something in your plugin which made it `false`, and you need to fix it.

What did you do wrong? It really depends. Open up `passes.c` and *find* that line, and see what it is checking. In my copy of GCC, the relevant function reads:

```
void
execute_ipa_pass_list (struct opt_pass *pass)
{
  do
    {
      /* An assertion.  */
      gcc_assert (!current_function_decl);
      /* Another assertion.  */
      gcc_assert (!cfun);
      /* Another assertion.  */
      gcc_assert (pass->type == SIMPLE_IPA_PASS || pass->type == IPA_PASS);
      if (execute_one_pass (pass) && pass->sub)
        {
          if (pass->sub->type == GIMPLE_PASS)
            {
              invoke_plugin_callbacks (PLUGIN_EARLY_GIMPLE_PASSES_START, NULL);
              do_per_function_toporder ((void (*)(void *))execute_pass_list,
                                        pass->sub);
              invoke_plugin_callbacks (PLUGIN_EARLY_GIMPLE_PASSES_END, NULL);
            }
          else if (pass->sub->type == SIMPLE_IPA_PASS
                   || pass->sub->type == IPA_PASS)
            execute_ipa_pass_list (pass->sub);
          else
            gcc_unreachable ();
        }
      /* Another assertion.  */
      gcc_assert (!current_function_decl);
      cgraph_process_new_functions ();
      pass = pass->next;
    }
  while (pass);
}
```

There are four `gcc_assert` statements. Your plugin caused one of them to become false. i.e. you messed with one of the variables:

```
current_function_decl
cfun
pass->type
```

This is probably what's wrong.